# misplaced constructs (Java)

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
    public void drawBoard(){
       System.out.println(P1 + "|" + P2 + "|" + P3 + "|"); 
       System.out.println(P4 + "|" + P5 + "|" + P6 + "|"); 
       System.out.println(P7 + "|" + P8 + "|" + P9 + "|");
    }
```

I get an underline under "public void drawBoard()" saying "syntax error on token(s) misplaced construct(s)"

I looked through the internet and through my Java text book and can not come up with a solution. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you,
   Allyn

Comment: What is P1, P2, P3, etc? Did you declare them anywhere?

Comment: probably error is some where else.

Comment: is this method inside `class`?

Comment: If your IDE underlines the first line of the method declaration, something might be not closed correctly before.

Comment: Show the whole class as the error might be in a method before that one.

Comment: What is P1 P2 P3... ????

Answer (score 3):

The

```
public void drawBoard() {
```

must appear directly inside a class definition.

If there is a method right before `drawBoard()`, make sure that you've closed all of its curly braces.